# Regular Expression for a REST endpoint

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone please help me in defining a regular expression for an endpoint.

```
person/^((?!-).)*$/
```

This regex needs to match a number of things but mainly:

```
person/:id
```

it should NOT match

```
person/1234-5678-9123 (it's currently not matching this which is good)
```

the problem I have is that it should NOT match this but it is:

```
person/123456789123 (it's currently matching this but shouldn't)
```

To be clear, If you go to: http://regex101.com and paste in:

```
^((?!-).)*$
```

You can see that is matches 123456789123 WHICH IS WRONG

How can I change the RegEx so it doesn't match 123456789123

Cheers.

Comment: I find myself interested in what you do want to match..

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `^((?!-).)*$` is same as `^[^-]*$` that is match any charcater but not of `-` zero or more times.

The reason for why your regex not matches this `person/1234-5678-9123` is because it has `-` symbol. But `person/123456789123` string isn't has `-` symbol, so this got matched.

To match the string which has `-` between the numbers then you could try the below regex.

```
^.*?\d+-\d+.*$
```

OR

```
^(?=.*?-).+$
```

`(?=.*?-)` Positive lookahead  asserts that the  string must contain an `-` symbol.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jL4jI4/1)

Comment: Thanks Avinash that has really helped.